# grabbing key and value from nested dict aws response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

I'm struggling to get my head around nested dicts and how to grab the key and value from them.

I have a nice script that grabs the VPC information from my AWS account:

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint

#Declaring some resources for the below scripts. 
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = boto3.client('ec2')

#Grabing the VPC information and printing to console. 
filters = [{'Name':'tag:Name', 'Values':['*']}]
vpcs = list(ec2.vpcs.filter(Filters=filters))

for vpc in vpcs:
    response = client.describe_vpcs(
        VpcIds=[
            vpc.id,
        ]
    )
    pprint(response['Vpcs'])
    print('-------')
```

This outputs like:

*[{'CidrBlock': '666.666.0.0/66',   'DhcpOptionsId': '55555',   'InstanceTenancy': 'default',   'IsDefault': False,'State': 'available',   'Tags': [{'Key': 'Environment', 'Value':'dev.aws'},
{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'dev.aws.co.uk'}],   'VpcId': 'vpc-755555'}]*

now what I want is to grab only the VpcId and Tags, I have tried multiple variations of pprint(response['Vpcs']["VpcId"]). I have searched the web and tried a number of variations but I can't seem to get my head around it

cany anyone offer any advice to my example?

**Update**:
thanks again are you able to assist with a follow on question?

I'm trying now to put this into a for loop so i can grab the output of any VPCs and Resulting tags that could be present in the AWS account but hitting a wall with "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Code i have tried (many variations of this):

```
  for vpcs in client.describe_vpcs():
    vpcid = vpcs['Vpcs'][0]['VpcId']
    print("Vpc Id:" + vpcid)

    for vpcs in client.describe_vpcs()['Vpcs']:
        print("VPC ID: " + vpcs['VpcId'])
        print(response['Vpcs'][0]['Tags'])
        print("Tags: " + vpcs['Tags'][0])
```

any ideas?

**Update 2:**

This loop works and will print out my VPCs with the tags of the fist VPC:

```
for vpcs in client.describe_vpcs()['Vpcs']:
    print("VPC ID: " + vpcs['VpcId'])
    print(response['Vpcs'][0]['Tags'])
```

I am trying to get it to loop the tags with the VPC id.

**Output of `print(client.describe_vpcs())`:**

`{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'nnnnn-e323-nn-a9a3-254nnnn2c3b6', 'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPHeaders': {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'AmazonEC2', 'date': 'Fri, 27 Jan 2017 14:21:58 GMT'}, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200}, 'Vpcs': [{'State': 'available', 'IsDefault': True, 'CidrBlock': '172.31.0.0/16', 'DhcpOptionsId': 'dopt-1d555578', 'VpcId': 'vpc-85555eb', 'InstanceTenancy': 'default', 'Tags': [{'Value': 'Default VPC', 'Key': 'Name'}]}, {'State': 'available', 'IsDefault': False, 'CidrBlock': '172.22.0.0/16', 'DhcpOptionsId': 'dopt-1d55558', 'VpcId': 'vpc-255554d', 'InstanceTenancy': 'default', 'Tags': [{'Value': 'DEV', 'Key': 'Environment'}, {'Value': 'dev2.aws.co.uk', 'Key': 'Name'}]}, {'State': 'available', 'IsDefault': False, 'CidrBlock': '172.30.0.0/16', 'DhcpOptionsId': 'dopt-16666d78', 'VpcId': 'vpc-7666617', 'InstanceTenancy': 'default', 'Tags': [{'Value': 'dev.aws', 'Key': 'Environment'}, {'Value': 'dev.aws.co.uk', 'Key': 'Name'}]}]}`

**Fix was:**

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')

#This is the VPC ID and Linked Tags
for vpctags in client.describe_vpcs()['Vpcs']: 
    print("VPC ID: ", vpctags['VpcId']) 
    print("Tags: ", vpctags['Tags'])
```

Big thanks to MYGz for taking the time to help.

Comment: Can you tell me the output of 1st `vpcs` in the for loop?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bena\workspacemars\aws.automated.tasks\trying_something_with_vpc_Dicts.py", line 27, in <module>
    vpcid = vpcs['Vpcs'][0]['VpcId']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: that is for the first loop

Comment: The 2nd Loop works "for vpcs in client.describe_vpcs()['Vpcs']:
    print("VPC ID: " + vpcs['VpcId'])
    print(response['Vpcs'][0]['Tags'])" but ofcourse it always prints out the same tags lol

Comment: updated my question

Comment: The error is here I guess: `for vpcs in client.describe_vpcs()['Vpcs']` Can you tell me the output of `print(client.describe_vpcs())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134196/discussion-between-mygz-and-ben).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need:

```
vpcid = response['Vpcs'][0]['VpcId']
        # ^dict    ^key  ^item  ^ key in dictionary
        #                at 0th
        #                position 
        #            (which is a dict)

tags = response['Vpcs'][0]['Tags']
```

`response['Vpcs']` returns a list. This list contains only 1 element. That 1 element is a dictionary that contains your desired entry `'VpcId'`

Values corresponding to keys in a dictionary are accessed by keys. And the values inside lists are accessed by index position.

For eg:

To access `'k4'` and get the value `'v4'` in the below dictionary

```
a={'k1': [{'k2': [{'k3': 'v3' }, {'k4': 'v4'}] }]}
```

You will have to do this:

```
a['k1'][0]['k2'][1]['k4']
```

Comment: are you able to assist with a follow on question? I'm trying now to put this into a for loop so i can grab the output of any VPCs and Resulting tags that could be present in the AWS account but hitting a wall with "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

  Code i have tried:
  for vpcs in client.describe_vpcs():
    vpcid = vpcs['Vpcs'][0]['VpcId']
    print("Vpc Id:" + vpcid)

    for vpcs in client.describe_vpcs()['Vpcs']:
        print("VPC ID: " + vpcs['VpcId'])
        print(response['Vpcs'][0]['Tags'])
        print("Tags: " + vpcs['Tags'][0])

  any ideas?

Comment: @ben Yeah if it's on the same topic.